# Getting user_posts permission approved?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've been working on a platform similar to http://vonvon.me and http://wittybunny.com which consists of little apps which users can try out with their facebook account logged in.

However I'm extremely annoyed that facebook is not approving the `user_posts` permission giving the following reason everytime:

[image]

I also created a video walking through how the app uses the permission at the backend to access user posts to determine number of likes on them and randomly choosing a friend on that basis, or maybe just determine the count of posts. I've submitted it 3 times but they have still the same response. What do I have to fix? My site: http://abfb.ml

Comment: @CBroe this is just an entertainment website. Facebook does not provide any way to access friend list so this is the closest I've got to access some recently interacted friends. Sites like vonvon and wittybunny are more or less doing the same things and they're approved. I'm not offended but you should really mind what you say.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's bit difficult to get this permission approved.
I had this same problem in one of my projects few months back. I used following steps carefully to get this approved.

- First, create a video that you can upload to facebook which contains the complete flow of your application.
- Start video with first home screen then go to login page.
- Then show how user will link his facebook account with your application. Show how user allow the different permissions
- Then go back to your application and try to show how you are going to use this permission. For eg if you are going to use this for post then try to show posting by your app.
- Last point, steps you are showing in the video should also be sent as text written when you submit it for app review.

This way i got my user_posts permission in my project.

Comment: Hey thanks for the information. what did you use user_posts for? I'm making use of it to get access to some recently interacted friends on top posts of users. How do I show them this thing?

Comment: I used this permission to get user's own posts details, as well as tagged, and for group posts .

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm asking for so much, but it would be really helpful if you could send that screencast which you submitted to facebook. It is uploaded in your profile somewhere. Thank you so much again :)

Comment: That was a complete video and steps in details that i mentioned above. You can refer to that. If any problem then let me know.